# Почему программа скомпилированная в Delphi XE почти в 2 раза больше чем в Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, компиляция, компилятор, delphi-xe

Есть очень маленькая программка. Когда я её компилирую в **Delphi 7**, то размер получается **590 кб**. Стоит эту же самую программку скомпилировать в **Delphi XE**, так она сразу же становиться в 2 раза больше размером - **1 200 кб**.

Что такого Delphi XE добавляет в исполняемый файл, что он увеличивается в размере?

Comment: уже почти 5 лет как этот вопрос обсудили
http://www.sql.ru/forum/887687/rezkoe-uvelichenie-razmera-exe-pri-perehode-s-delphi-2007-na-delphi-xe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Много всякого разного. Попробуйте поискать на сайте Embarcadero что конкретно добавилось.
Если Вам нужно уменьшить размер исполняемого файла, добавьте в файл проекта следующее:

```
programm MyProg;

{$IFNDEF DEBUG}
  {$WEAKLINKRTTI ON}        // если вам не нужны новые возможности RTTI!
  {$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([]) FIELDS([]) PROPERTIES([])}    // если вам не нужны новые возможности RTTI!
{$ENDIF}

uses
...
  Windows;

{$IFNDEF DEBUG}
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED} // Удаление из exe таблицы релокаций.
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_DEBUG_STRIPPED} //  Удаление из ехе Debug информации
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LINE_NUMS_STRIPPED} // Удаление из exe информации о номерах строк
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LOCAL_SYMS_STRIPPED} // Удаление local symbols
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP} //При запуске exe с компакта, флэшки, других извлекаемых устройств, считать exe в свап и запустить оттуда. Полезно, если нужно запустить программу с компакта, а потом попросить вставить другой...
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP} // Аналогично предыдущей, только для сетевых дисков
  {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE}
{$ENDIF}
```

Размер файла в конфигурации `Release` значительно уменьшится.